# What color sets are there?

Tags: color

I've got a music player that colors the playlist songs according to various criteria, and recently I've changed the random color generator to a static list of traditional japanese colors. That made the interface so prettier that I want to repeat the deed!

I was wondering if there are more of these "traditional color sets", or any great collection of colors I could borrow for my users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try adobe Kuler / http://kuler.adobe.com/
2. Try Colourlovers / http://www.colourlovers.com/

These sites allow you to create sets of colours. There are plenty of predefined colour sets available.